# Is it possible for a user or hacker to call a POST action method using some tools outside the application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I was reading about an example on Microsoft web site on how to show or hide a “Register” link for an object depend on whether the current user is already registered or not.
They add the following code to the view to display the Register link only if the current user is not already registered:-

```
<div id=”rsvpmsg”>
<% if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { %>
<% if (Model.IsUserRegistered(Context.User.Identity.Name)) { %>
<p>You are registered for this event!</p>
<% } else { %>
<%: Ajax.ActionLink( “RSVP for this event”,
“Register”, “RSVP”,
new { id=Model.DinnerID },
new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId=”rsvpmsg” }) %>
```

then on the register action method they also perform the same check to check if the user is already registered or not as follow:-

```
    [Authorize, HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(int id) {
    Dinner dinner = dinnerRepository.GetDinner(id);
    if (!dinner.IsUserRegistered(User.Identity.Name)) {
    RSVP rsvp = new 

RSVP();
// .....
```

So my question is why they perform the same check on the Post action method again,,, **is there a chance for a user to call the POST register action method other than clicking on the Register link that will not be displayed if the user is already register ?** ... so why not to consider the

```
 if (!dinner.IsUserRegistered(User.Identity.Name))
```

check on the action method as unnecessary ?
BR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's decidedly possible, and very easy.

Comment: so this mean that i should performe the same check on the controller side again?

Comment: +1. Bits flowing across the network that you don't want might be crafted to look exactly the same as bits that you *do* want.

Comment: By all means.  Never trust data from the user, and never assume anything about what the user did or didn't do.  That's one of the basic tenets of web security.

Comment: yes, never trust the user input and always validate the response on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have used this for testing. Fiddler ( http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ ) for example will let you create / edit requests then send them as well as view them

Comment: thanks for ur reply; but will the fiddler tool able to work and access views even if i use the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] before the Register POST action method, and i use the Html.AntiForgeryToken() on the page that contains the Register link ?

Comment: Yes, HTTP is a stateless protocol. I just sends another request.